# Is only outbound connectivity failure a thing? (Inbound works well)

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, linux-networking

I conducted the following test scenario as part of resiliency tests on the micro-service I wrote.

```
TEST : BLOCK ALL OUTBOUND TRAFFIC and ALLOW ALL INBOUND TRAFFIC.
```

I can't think of a real world scenario where such a thing is possible, unless there is some deliberate fiddling with the network/routing/ip tables or firewalls.

I was wondering if there is a real-world equivalent for the above test scenario, provided that there was no issue with firewalls and network/routing/ip tables settings when the micro-service was deployed.

Can someone enlighten me.

Regards.

---

PS:
My micro-service will run as AWS ECS in an VPC, connected to the outside world via an ELB.

Comment: Why only "deliberate fiddling"? Many widescale network issues are a result of misconfigurations...

Comment: I agree. But I am assuming a situation where in all the configurations went in fine during the deploy and this failure is mostly intermittent in nature.

Comment: I guess this is a wide scoped question, so to narrow down, Is such a intermittent failure scenario possible in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to carefully define "traffic," because there are multiple failure modes matching your description.

Assuming TCP, there are at least two distinct sets of conditions that appear to match the description, with opposite effects.

- if outbound *packets* are being dropped, then inbound connections be affected as well.  One-way transmission on network links, or a network ACL misconfiguration could trigger this.  Route asymmetry is routine on the Internet, and by extension this failure could have many causes.  In such a failure, workload demand on the service is likely to decrease dramatically because connections can't be established either direction, but overloads of SYN packets would not be unexpected.
- If outbound *connections* fail (TCP sessions can't be established) but inbound connections succeed, that's a very different scenario.  With a layer 7 load balancer, this condition could easily occur, due to the fact that the service receives its inbound requests on a different path than are handling its outbound requests.  Route table or Network ACL misconfiguration, or NAT device failure or misconfigurarion could trigger this, or VPC endpoint issues, or failure of a networking component in an underlying resource (e.g. a database or API that your service accesses).  In this condition, the workload on your service spikes up, because each request requires more runtime while it tries and fails to contact resources on which it depends.

Either of these conditions can and do occur in the real world for reasons both within and outside your control.  Item #1 on the list of the [Fallacies of Distributed Computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing) is "the network is reliable."

False.